# Import multiple IP addresses within an array as object

Tags: powershell, import

I am trying to import the following data using PowerShell:

```
Name                 AllowedIPAddresses                              Enabled
activeDirectoryAll   {AA.BB.28.1,AA.BB.28.2,AA.BB.124.1,AA.BB.124.2} TRUE
CIMHttpServer        {AA.BB.134.77}                                  TRUE
CIMHttpsServer       {AA.BB.134.77}                                  TRUE
CIMSLP               {AA.BB.21.128/26}                               TRUE
cmmds                {All}                                           FALSE
dhcp                 {All}                                           FALSE
```

When I import the `AllowedIPAddresses` into an array with the command

```
$Srcdata = Import-Csv -Path $SrcFWFile
```

This data has the following type:

```
AllowedIPAddresses NoteProperty System.String AllowedIPAddresses={All}
```

however the date needs to be this type:

```
AllowedIPAddresses NoteProperty System.Object[] AllowedIPAddresses=System.Object[]
```

How can I manipulate this column so that I can insert these as multiple IPs within a `System.Object`?

Comment: Is your input file comma separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the curly brackets and split the string at commas:

```
Import-Csv -Path $SrcFWFile | Select-Object -Property *,@{n='AllowedIPAddresses';e={$_.AllowedIPAddresses -replace '^\{|\}$' -split ','}} -Exclude AllowedIPAddresses
```

Comment: This part of powershell always annoyed me. I wish there was an easier way to manipulate one value of an object array. Works fine for `import-csv` though. Could also just use `.Trim("{}")` instead of regex

Comment: @Matt It shouldn't be too complicated to wrap this in a custom function `Update-Property` that accepts pipeline inpute and takes two additional arguments: the property name (string) and the operation (scriptblock).

Comment: @Matt No argument there.

Comment: Thanks both with a bit of coaxing i managed to get it to work :)